# message.createDraftReplyAll not working for mail received in BCC

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail-api

I am marking a mail in the inbox with a label.
Then I am making a draft reply from Google Sheet to that mail.
It is working perfectly if I received the mail in To or CC. But if the mail was received in BCC, I am getting an error "Invalid CC headers"

Not able to find out why.

Is there a way I can sense if I received that mail as Bcc?

```
    var filter = "label:"+ofrno+" is:important in:Starred";
    var threads = GmailApp.search(filter);  
    if (threads){
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) { // Loop through the threads
      var thisThread = threads[i]; // Get a speific thread
      var messages = thisThread.getMessages(); // Get the messages in that thread
      var message = messages[0]; // first message
    }
    }
    if (message){
      var draft = message.createDraftReplyAll('',
        {
            htmlBody: body ,
            attachments:  [theBlob] ,
        }
      );
    } else {
      var draft = GmailApp.createDraft(cusvals[0][4],"Quotation " + ofrno +" from xxx","",
        {
            htmlBody: body ,
            attachments:  [theBlob] ,
        }
      );
    }
```

Comment: I tested a few things but what I find interesting is that if the filter is `bcc:me` on its own then the draft is created - but `bcc:me is:important in:Starred` also throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

#### This appears to be a bug!

I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [Unable to create a Draft reply all if mail was received via BCC](https://issuetracker.google.com/231427384)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.

Comment: Google has assigned it to someone (after one year)!!!!

Comment: @arulselvan I hate to say it but it doesn't mean anything, I wouldn't get your hopes up...